# How to store data in localstorage before user exits page user react-router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I want to store some data in localstorage right before user navigates to another page. I have tried using useBeforeUnload but it does not work.

```
  useBeforeUnload(
    useCallback(() => {
      localStorage.setItem(`formCreation${id}${revisionNo}`, formData);
    }, [])
  );
```

I also tried using window.addEventListener beforeunload but since its a single page application using react router, even if user routes to another page it won't store the data in localstorage.

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (event)
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: In what way does it not work? Does the callback not run?

Answer (score 0):

The `beforeunload` event, i.e. when the browser window/tab is closed or the user is navigating to another external URL entirely, isn't the same as a React component simply unmounting, i.e. when a link is clicked the React app navigates to an internal route path.

If you want to capture some value to save to localStorage when the route the component is rendered on is navigated away from then use a `useEffect` hook's cleanup function to do then when the component unmounts. Since you only want this effect to run once, you'll likely need to couple this logic with another `useEffect` hook and a React ref to cache a value you want to persist when the component unmounts.

```js
const formDataRef = React.useRef();

useEffect(() => {
  formDataRef.current = formData;
}, [formData]);

useEffect(() => {
  () => {
    localStorage.setItem(`formCreation${id}${revisionNo}`, formDataRef.current);
  };
}, []);
```

If you want to cover both cases of component unmounting ***and*** the browser context being closed/unloaded then combine the above along with the `beforeunload` event listener.

Example:

```js
const formDataRef = React.useRef();

useEffect(() => {
  formDataRef.current = formData;
}, [formData]);

useEffect(() => {
  const saveData = () => {
    localStorage.setItem(`formCreation${id}${revisionNo}`, formDataRef.current);
  };

  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', saveData);

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', saveData);
    saveData();
  };
}, []);
```